# SpringBoot integrated tomcat: configure to limit requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-7

Ahoi,

I build a little RESTful Webservice with spring boot with integrated tomcat. Then I tried to test how robust it is I found that sending many HTTP requests (with apache benchmark) dramatically increases memory usage until the service fails because of an OutOfMemoryException - also it seems not to be able to recover within reasonable time.

I could not find any documentation on how to configure the integrated tomcat e.g. to limit the amount of requets by IP (or what else would make sense?). Also I wonder if there are any known memory leaks, as a few 1000 requests shouldnt really bring the tomcat down (I run the .jar with -Xms512m -Xmx1024m)

I appreciate your help!

Comment: as i did a similar thing just last week, i'd say, you have a memory leak in your code... (because it was fine on my tests)

Comment: Actually I am pretty sure there's no memory leak. When giving the process more memory it does not crash and visualizing the memory usage with visualVM shows that it always goes back to a reasonable baseline shortely after the bulk bench requests. Maybe my question should rather be: how to config tomcat not to crash =(

Comment: Maybe if you can share a simple project that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Tomcat has such a filter built in, but it should be pretty trivial to add a `javax.servlet.Filter` of your own for this purpose. The [`RateLimiter` class from Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) is an excellent resource for limiting something like how many requests allowed per IP in a time window.